# Blender to Unity Mesh Deformation

Tags: animation, bones, unity

[image: The deformation in unity]
[image: The rig in blender]
[image]
Animations and model looks great in blender. I import into unity and it this deformation happens and I can't seem to get rid of it.The animations all play correctly in unity but the deformation on the hand is always present.
Things I don't know about

- This model/rig uses plenty of IKs in blender so I am not sure if that translates into unity although i haven't had problems from it in the past
- This model also uses the child-of constraint in blender and in the animations the influence value is changed.

Things I have tried.

- Applying and reapplying LocRotScale
- Removing re-applying armature
- Messing around with unity model settings (i.e. rig from generic to legacy, mesh compression etc.)
- Double checked weight painting and all vertices are correctly assigned.

the model can be downloaded [here](https://georgefabish.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Player.zip)

Comment: Things you should post a pic of: What the bone structure in the affected arm looks like, and Unity's console (is it reporting errors?) . Alternatively, you can post the file itself and we can take a look.

Comment: I added a link for download. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlL9Ez9SyS0) tutorial to develop the hand rig. There were no unity warnings/errors on import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default importer is doing no such thing for me when I put it into Unity with the default (click + drag) importer.
[image: All included animation clips]
I suspect that the issue is purely on Unity's side.  The version of Unity I am using is 
2018.3.2f1.  You might want to try updating your Unity and Blender versions.

Comment: Great! That was the problem. Drag and drop wasn't working for me. Turns out in unity 2019.1 (the version i am using) updated their blenderToFBX.py file to work with blender2.8 but I am still using blender 2.79. I reverted that file back to unity2018.3's version and the drag and drop started working. The curious thing is exporting straight from blender to FBX is still causing that distortion in unity. But the drag and drop doesn't have any distortion. Oh well.

Comment: Good deal.  The FBX exporter in terms of Unity seems a little unstable for me right now, so you might want to export manually and tweak the setting so you know what's good.  If this helped, remember to mark this question as answered.